# Python & Wxpython | This program needs access to the screen?

Tags: python, macos, pip, wxpython

**Goal: Use ESPHome Flasher** https://github.com/esphome/esphome-flasher

TLDR: Starting esphomeflasher I get this error message:

```
This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a
Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in
on the main display of your Mac.
```

Python Setup: https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac

Mac Setup: Fresh Catalina installation.

Steps:

1. `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
2. `brew install pyenv`
3. `pyenv install 3.9.1`
4. `pyenv global 3.9.1`
5. `echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc`
6. `pip install --upgrade pip`

**Install esphomeflasher:** https://github.com/esphome/esphome-flasher

Steps:

1. `pip3 install wxpython`
2. `pip3 install esphomeflasher`

Problem:

Starting esphomeflasher I get the following error:

```
This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a
Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in
on the main display of your Mac.
```

I found this but don't know how to apply it in my case.

https://blurringexistence.net/wxpython-using-virtualenvwrapper-on-osx.html

My .zshrc config:

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH

# We want to regularly go to our virtual environment directory
echo 'export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs' >> .zshrc
# If in a given virtual environment, make a virtual environment directory
# If one does not already exist
echo 'mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME' >> .zshrc
# Activate the new virtual environment by calling this script
# Note that $USER will substitute for your current user
echo '. ~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh' >> .bash_profile
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
```